# Working Out Big O Of Functions Using Java + Excel

Tags: excel, big-o

I have been trying to get the big O of four different functions using java and excel. I have no idea what these functions are as they have been hidden. I am not sure if this is the right place / forum to ask.

I have got the functions to give various pieces of data using some java and put them into excel along with the steps (1-n). I then put them into graphs straight away using just the n and the arbitrary measure of time they took if the output was constantly the same. For example if n = 1 always equal 200 for every time its run. For the ones that varied each time the function was run I ran the function 10 times and did an average for each step.

After I had the data I created a graph for each one and put a trendline on it. My f(1) for example was best fitted to a polynomial trendline order 2, which I assume is Quadratic (n2) of big O?. But I needed to prove it was n2, so I did =Steps/LOG(N) which made it fit best to a polynomial trendline order 3, which I assume is Cubic (n3)? (Is that right?)

I really have no idea what to do next to 'prove' that this function is Quadratic or Cubic or how to prove its best case / worst case.

So basically I am trying to work out what the missing step is.

Computation
Graph
Trendline
??? - Proof that the function has big O(?)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "if n=1 always equal 200" does that mean if n=1 it takes 200 *steps* to run? If that's the case this function would be 200n and this O(n).

I think to solve this you should call each function on different values (I'd start with 10, 20, 30 ... ect) up to some high number. Capture these values and plot them in Excel. Then use the built in trend line function. This should give you a rough estimate of what the run time is. From there you should be able to get the Big-O.